# Form Submit Result to FancyBox

Tags: jquery, forms, fancybox

There is a form on my page.
It has an image submit button.
Is there a way to open the submission result in a fancybox iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think of doing this.

- You submit form via ajax and on "success" callback have a function that triggers fancybox open.

Using jQuery you could do something like this.

```
$(function(){
  $("#id_of_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var req = $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $(this).attr("action"),
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       dataType: "json"
    });

    req.success(function(resp){
     //resp is data back from server
        //Here you write logic for opening the fancybox iframe              
    });

  });

});
```

Hope this helps.